# Nsis Error while installing Sql Express

Tags: nsis, sql-server-express

Using following function to Sql Express using Nsis But getting error while running this function named InstallSQL the function is shown below

```
Function  InstallSQL

File /oname=$TEMP\SQLEXPR32.exe Prerequisites\SQLEXPR32.exe
ExecWait '$TEMP\SQLEXPR32.exe /Q /ACTION=Install /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ROLE=AllFeatures_WithDefaults /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /INSTANCENAME=STELLSQL /SecurityMode=SQL /SAPWD="neptune" /IndicateProgress'

FunctionEnd
```

below is the image of error

[image]

Comment: Does it work when NSIS is not involved; just executing it in a terminal or Start>Run?

Comment: I don't think `/Q` is right, but `/qn` or `/qs` instead.  But as Anders said, need to get it working silently from command line first to verify the switches are right before embedding in the NSIS.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to answer, but it will be helpful who refer this page.

I have installed SQL Express 2014 SP1 with silent installation using nsis script which works successfully.

```
Function  InstallSQL

     ExecWait '"$temp\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.EXE" /Q /ACTION=Install /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /FEATURES=SQL,SSMS /INSTANCENAME="SQLEXPRESS2014" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /SQLSVCStartupType=Automatic /AddCurrentUserAsSqlAdmin /ENABLERANU=1 /hideconsole /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="Sql@1234" /AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Manual /NPENABLED=1 /TCPENABLED=1'

FunctionEnd
```

Note:  You can specify setup location instead of `$temp`